# RCLL (cadlag) But Not Bounded Variation

Tags: probability, bounded-variation

In probability theory, we often require that functions and/or processes be RCLL (i.e. cadlag) and of bounded variation (usually bounded on any finite interval).  I'm having trouble coming up with an example of a deterministic function which is RCLL but not of bounded variation.  In other words, I'm wondering why the bounded variation condition is not redundant.  Thanks.